# How can I have % of width of an img wrapped in a specific div width?

Tags: html, css, image

I just wrapped an image into a div so that I could control exactly the position of my image when the screen is resized. Everything worked so fine, like, a left part was hid when I resize and so the right part was hid too at my specification. But It appears that my img stay the same width, so there's that annoying horizontal scroll bar.

Here's my live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/U3pB9/11/

**HTML**:

```html
<div id="slideShow">
    <img id="ss1" src="http://i.imgur.com/gDRF4rO.jpg">
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#slideShow {
    width:1200px;
    height:329px;
    margin:auto;
}

#ss1 {
    width:1920px;
    height:329px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    left:-360px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-bottom:3px solid rgb(254,199,73);
}
```

So, I tried to have a dynamic weight for my picture, equal to the user screen width but it won't just work. The number was right when the screen is resized but the image width was just wrong. I tried to put a overflow:hidden in my img id, but then again, nothing happen. The scroll bar is still there when you resize the window.

So, when you resize your screen, how to hide that horizontal scroll bar? How to get rid of that right part of the picture?

---

EDIT PART

Due to my bad english (lol), here's two picture of what I am trying to achieve :

Lets say the user has a 1920px screen width.
My image will look like this :
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=29zat0&s=8#.UxSJ5_nxo9U

Then, if the user resize his window to, lets say around 1700, or even 1500 px, my picture will look like this :
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=241qpvl&s=8#.UxSJ_Pnxo9U

So as you see, 1200px of my image is centered even when the window is resized until the screen size get 1200px width. So a left part of the image is hid as a right part of the image is hid too! (Then, when the screen will get 1200px, I will just resize it with media queries in %)

Comment: Could you have the image as a background so that its width doesn't affect the page flow? Or perhaps use a dynamic `@media` query to change the width depending upon the page size? Also, the overflow only makes sense if it's on `#slideshow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

Width is set explicitly. Since the width of the child is larger than the parent, the child will overflow.

[edit] To remove the scroll bar, essentially it's the same problem. Setting overflow: hidden to the child will only affect the child and not the parent. In this case #slideShow will overflow because hidden only affects #ss1.

### Solution

Set the width of both the child to 100%. This means it will be 100% of the width of the container.

[edit] Set overflow on the affected parents. In this case it's #slideShow's parent or

### Example

```
body {
  overflow: hidden; /*removes scrollbar on the body */
  width: 100%;
}

#slideShow {
  width: 100%; /* Sets width to body */
}

#ss1 {
  width: 100%; /* Sets widht to #slideShow */
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's working just fine but then again, I have a problem. (My real picture has 1920 px width though..) When I resize my screen, I want 360px of the left hid by the window. So that when I resize at exactly 1200px, my img still looks centered. In your solution, my picture is narrowed too much. (I have txt in my img, and it's impossible to read)

Comment: I don't follow what you want, would you be able to draw what you want in Paint and post it so I can get a better idea of what you need?

Comment: I did a edit part with two pictures to try explain it further!

Comment: Nice!! I set overflow:hidden on body and set a width of 100% and it works. Scroll bar has disappear so that user wont see the right part of my img. But, I stayed with #slideshow width: 1200px and #ss1 at width 1920px. :) Thanks you! (This is what it looks like at the end http://jsfiddle.net/U3pB9/12/)

Comment: Is this what you want? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/P5b5C/) I can update my solution if this is the effect you want.

Comment: just look at my jsfiddle on the other comment. (You have to size your window pretty wide so that you see the entire image, then slowly resize the width of it...You'll see that the picture will still be centered until around 1200px.!)